# Django. Передача файла пользователю

Tags: python, django

Прошу вашей подсказки.

Идея следующая, есть форма, где я предлагаю пользователю дать ссылку например на страничку в ВК, с этой странички я скачаю аватарку и отдам пользователю на скачивание по готовности. Ту самую аватарку, т.е. кнопка на все про все - одна.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
def main_site(request):

form = First_Form()
if request.method == 'POST':
    post = Post()
    link = request.POST['text'] # Ссылка, которую получил от юзера
    post.text = link
    try:
        ...Псевдокод получения картинки...
        photo.save() # Готово, фотография у меня.
        print("well done!")
        ...Вот тут код, который отдаст пользователю картинку, которую только что получил...
    except:
        print('error')
        pass
    return render(request, 'main/base_page.html', {'form': form})
else:
    return render(request, 'main/base_page.html', {'form': form})
```

Никак не могу понять и найти информацию, как передать автоматически пользователю файл?
Должен ли я формировать ссылку href и прикручивать к "кнопке"? Или какие-то есть варианты другие?

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если картинку получаешь как байты:

```
import io
from django.http import FileResponse

def some_view(request):
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    buffer.write(picture_content)
    buffer.seek(0)
    return FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename='filename.jpg')
```

Если картинка файл, то ещё проще

```
import io
from django.http import FileResponse

def some_view(request):
    return FileResponse(open('filename.jpg','rb'))
```